# Problem when using FlashList in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit, react-native-flatlist

this code is supposed to load infinite data using pagination with RTK Query and Flash list.
Data is coming normally without issues the only issue is it loads all data at once and ignores the onEndReached functionality.
after monitoring the server once the page loads it loads all 5 pages at once without even touching the list

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { useGetLatestArticlesQuery } from "../data/articleQuery";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import ArticleListItem from "./articleSingleItem";

const HomeArticlesList = ({ limit }) => {
  [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);
  const [isLoadingMore, setIsLoadingMore] = useState(false);
  const { data, isLoading, refetch } = useGetLatestArticlesQuery(limit, page);
  if (isLoading) {
    // Render loading state or placeholder
    return <ActivityIndicator size="large" />;
  }
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    // Check if item is defined before rendering
    if (!item) {
      console.warn("Item is null or undefined:", item);
      return null;
    }

    return <ArticleListItem item={item} />;
  };
  const keyExtractor = (item) =>
    item ? item.id.toString() : Math.random().toString();
  const renderSeparator = () => {
    return <View style={styles.separator} />;
  };
  if (isLoadingMore) {
    // Render loading state or placeholder
    return <ActivityIndicator size="large" />;
  }
  const onEndReached = () => {
    setIsLoadingMore(true);
    setPage(page + 1);
    if (page != 1 && page < 5) {
      refetch();
    }
    setIsLoadingMore(false);
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          disableVirtualization={true}
          removeClippedSubviews={true}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={60}
          windowSize={30}
          data={data}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={renderSeparator}
          onEndReached={onEndReached}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
          estimatedItemSize={100}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: "100%",
    padding: 12,
  },
  separator: {
    height: 10,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
  },
});
export default HomeArticlesList;
```

RTK query functions

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import Config from "../utils/Config";

const apiUrl = Config.API_BASE_URL;

export const articlesApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "articlesApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: apiUrl,
  }),
  refetchOnFocus: true,
  refetchOnReconnect: true,
  tagTypes: [
    "articlesByCategory",
    "featuredArticles",
    "latestArticles",
    "relatedArticles",
  ],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getArticlesByCategory: builder.query({
      query: (category_id) => ({
        url: `/articles?category=${category_id}&limit=20&page=${page}`,
        method: "GET",
      }),
      // Always merge incoming data to the cache entry
      merge: (currentCache, newItems) => {
        currentCache.push(...newItems);
      },
      // Refetch when the page arg changes
      forceRefetch({ currentArg, previousArg }) {
        return currentArg !== previousArg;
      },
      providesTags: (result, error, category_id, page) =>
        result
          ? [{ type: "articlesByCategory", id: category_id, page: page }]
          : [],
    }),
    getFeaturedArticles: builder.query({
      query: () => ({
        url: "/articles/featured",
        method: "Get",
      }),
      providesTags: ["featuredArticles"],
    }),
    getLatestArticles: builder.query({
      query: ({ limit, page }) => ({
        url: `/articles?limit=${limit}&page=${page}`,
        method: "Get",
      }),
      // Always merge incoming data to the cache entry
      merge: (currentCache, newItems) => {
        currentCache.push(...newItems);
      },
      // Refetch when the page arg changes
      forceRefetch({ currentArg, previousArg }) {
        return currentArg !== previousArg;
      },
      providesTags: (result, error, limit, page) =>
        result ? [{ type: "latestArticles", limit: limit, page: page }] : [],
    }),
    getRelatedArticles: builder.query({
      query: (article_id) => ({
        url: `/articles/related/${article_id}?limit=10&page=${page}`,
        method: "Get",
      }),
      // Always merge incoming data to the cache entry
      merge: (currentCache, newItems) => {
        currentCache.push(...newItems);
      },
      // Refetch when the page arg changes
      forceRefetch({ currentArg, previousArg }) {
        return currentArg !== previousArg;
      },
      providesTags: (result, error, article_id, page) =>
        result
          ? [{ type: "relatedArticles", article_id: article_id, page: page }]
          : [],
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetArticlesByCategoryQuery,
  useGetFeaturedArticlesQuery,
  useGetLatestArticlesQuery,
  useGetRelatedArticlesQuery,
} = articlesApi;
```

i kept track of

```
const onEndReached = () => {
    setIsLoadingMore(true);
    setPage(page + 1);
    if (page != 1 && page < 5) {
      console.log(page);
      refetch();
    }
```

by logging anything just to watch how it works and unfortunately it prints all page numbers once the app loaded without even touching the list

Answer (score 0):

I expect that `onEndReached` were instantly triggered due to value of `onEndReachedThreshold` which will call `refetch` which trigger a rerender and so on...

To test my assumption increase the row height to for instance to 300 so that
`onEndReachedThreshold` only get called 4 times

Comment: I figured out the problem
the main screen has a Scroll View component and that its why the Flashlist counts its height as part of it and calls onEndReached function once the screen loaded